# Input file type validation message not displaying

Tags: jquery, validation, input

I have a file upload field in my form and I am validating that field using jquery validation like the following:

My Input tag:

```
<input type="file"  id="photo" name="photo" />
```

Validation:

```
    $('#create_teacher').validate({
    rules: {
        photo:{
            required: true,
             extension: "jpeg,jpg,gif,png"
        },
    },
    messages: {
        photo: { // <- this refers to the NAME attribute, NOT id.
            required: "this field is mandatory",
            extension: "accepts jpeg, jpg, gif or png"
        }
    }
  });
```

can anyone help me in this .

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice?  Also, this question doesn't have an actual question in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input file validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294479/input-file-validation)